# Split value of specific index of array into two separate values which will be another subarray

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have issue where I have array like this:

```
array1: [
    1 => array:1 [
         "category" => array2 [
                       "id" => 1
                       "category_name" => portable/fun
    ]
]
```

I wish I could split values of "category_name" into another subarray with two separate values "portable" and "fun".

It should look something like this:

```
array1: [
    1 => array:1 [
         "category" => array2 [
                   "id" => 1
                   "category_name" => array:2 [
                                      1 => portable
                                      2 => fun
       ]
    ]
]
```

I know how to split this one value but how can I push it as a subarray like in my example?

Or maybe there is another simplified way to get result I need?

Comment: `[][]['category_name'] = explode('/', [][]['category_name'])`?

Comment: At first glance I thought PHP added new operator of `[][]` for recursive find... @u_mulder :D

Comment: Does my solution solve your problem? If not, I am happy to remove my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursive approach to achieve the same,

```
array_walk_recursive ($arr, function(&$v,$k){
  if($k == 'category_name'){ // check recursively if $k is category_name
        $v = explode("/",$v); // replace value with explode result 
  }
});
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/ReSnB).